# The nature of variables within proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, predicate-logic

I am confused about how best to view certain kinds of variables that show up in the course of an elementary proof. For example, to prove that the square of every odd integer is odd, I would write:

Let $m \in \mathbf{Z}$ be arbitrary. Suppose $m$ is odd. Choose $k \in \mathbf{Z}$ such that $m = 2k + 1$. Then $m^2 = (2k + 1)^2 = 2(2k^2 + 2k) + 1$, so since $2k^2 + 2k \in \mathbf{Z}$, it follows that $m^2$ is odd.

The symbol $m$ is introduced as part of the technique of universal generalization; Velleman [1] describes this step as "introducing a new variable [$m$] ... to stand for an arbitrary object." The symbol $k$ is introduced as part of the technique of existential instantiation; [1] describes this as "introducing a new variable [$k$] to stand for an object for which [the predicate $m = 2k + 1$] is true."

In what sense are $m$ and $k$ variables? They do not seem to be bound variables, as they are in the scope of no quantifier. They also can't be free variables, because if they were, then, for example, the sentence being proved true after the introduction of arbitrary integer $m$ -- namely that if $m$ is odd then $m^2$ is odd -- would be a predicate and not even have a truth value; I am also obviously not free to substitute values into $m$ and $k$, if for no other reason than $m$ and $k$ are dependent.

Stoll [2] says a variable is free if it is not bound, so there is no third option.

Is it more correct to think of the phrases "let $m \in \mathbf{Z}$ be arbitrary" and "choose $k \in \mathbf{Z}$ such that ..." as introducing new *constants* rather than variables, as their values are fixed despite being unspecified ($m$) or unknown ($k$)? More generally, the idea of a symbol that stands for a particular but arbitrary element of some set seems incompatible with the typical description of a variable as a placeholder as seen in, e.g., Epp [3].

---

[1] Velleman, D. (2006). How to Prove It: A Structured Approach (2nd ed.). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

[2] Stoll, Robert Roth (1963). Set Theory and Logic. W.H. Freeman.

[3] Epp, Susanna S. Variables in Mathematics Education. [https://condor.depaul.edu/~sepp/VariablesInMathEd.pdf](https://condor.depaul.edu/%7Esepp/VariablesInMathEd.pdf)

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822741/logic-justification-for-the-use-of-let-y-in-existential-proof) very similar post as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799062/basic-question-about-proofs-with-the-goal-exists-x-px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

universal generalization: "for all odd $m \in \Bbb{Z}$".

existential instantiation: "there exists a $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $m = 2k+1$".

These are both quantified and they are quantified in the way you recite.

It is more accurate to think of variables as variables.  A statement with a universally quantified variable may be specialized, removing the universal quantifier, by replacing the occurrences of the variable with a particular member of the set from which that variable is drawn.  For instance, in your proof, an equally valid set of statements is produced by replacing every instance of $m$ by "$3$" (an odd integer).  Existentially quantified variables can be specialized to the value that satisfies their constraints.

When $m$ is generic (free to range over the odd integers), $k$ must be generic, since the value of $k$ is dependent on the value of $m$.  (In a more pedantic setting, the dependence of $k$ on $m$ would be made more apparent by writing, for instance $k(m)$, $k_m$, or some other syntax to indicate dependency.  This dependency enforces an order on the quantifiers.  Equivalently, the order of the quantifiers, $\forall m \text{ odd}, \exists k \in \Bbb{Z} \dots$.)  Even though $k$ is generic, in this case, we can solve for $k$ in terms of $m$: $k = \frac{m-1}{2}$.  Consequently, throughout, we may specialize the variable $k$ to the value $\frac{m-1}{2}$.

When $m$ is specialized to a value, we may replace $k$ with the value that is half of one less than the value of $m$.  We still end up with a valid set of statements -- this valid set of statements is the explicit proof of the oddness of the square of whatever value $m$ has taken.  This last should make it clear: $m$ and $k$ are variables.  For each specialization of $m$ and $k$ to (valid) values, we obtain a concrete proof.  If we do not specialize, we obtain a proof that is universally quantified over $m$ and existentially quantified over $k$ (which is dependent on $m$).

Comment: This is helpful, but I still have some confusion. Here's a simpler example: In the sentence "$x < 3$", $x$ is considered a free variable, and the sentence is a predicate and thus has no truth value; we are free to substitute a value for $x$ to produce a proposition. But if we precede this sentence by "Let $x$ be an arbitrary number", the meaning of $x$ in "$x < 3$" seems to change, and I don't get precisely what changes -- we now apparently have a proposition despite $x$ being generic. In the latter case, is the truth value of the proposition $x < 3$ the same as that of $\forall x(x < 3)$?

Comment: In other words, even though we manipulate an arbitrary element in the proof body as though it were a single object, it is more like multiple proofs are running in parallel -- one per specialization of the arbitrary object.

Comment: @ColeArora : "it is more like multiple proofs are running in parallel -- one per specialization of the arbitrary object" -- this much is exactly right.  If it turns out that the proof works for all possible specializations, then the proof works when the variable that is specialized is universally quantified.  When one writes "Let $x$ be an arbitrary number", one is asserting $\forall x \in \text{numbers}$, so of course the subsequent assertion "$x < 3$", with $x$ a free variable, is interpreted as "$\forall x \in \text{numbers}, x < 3$", with $x$ universally quantified.

Answer (score 2):

> In what sense are $m$ and $k$ variables? They do not seem to be bound variables, as they are in the scope of no quantifier.

Actually every time you say something like "let $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ be arbitrary" the word "arbitrary" is code for an implicit universal quantifier $\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}$, in this case part of the statement

$$\forall m \in \mathbb{Z} : \left( \exists k \in \mathbb{Z} : 2k+1 = m \right) \Rightarrow \left( \exists k' \in \mathbb{Z} : 2k'+1 = m^2 \right)$$

you are trying to prove. So it is a bound variable, bound to a quantifier which is being left implicit. This is a very common convention in mathematics which is usually not described explicitly. Then we appeal to a general principle about how to prove a result involving a universal quantifier, which I guess is called [universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization): to prove $\forall m, P(m)$ you introduce $m$ as an arbitrary variable and write down a proof where you assume nothing about $m$ except whatever premises might be in the statement $P(m)$ and see if you can deduce the desired conclusion.

Comment: Is there a book you could recommend that expands on this? I've never seen proof methods described this way.

Comment: @Cole: unfortunately I've never seen this explained anywhere in writing (not that I've tried to look). Again, it's the sort of thing which is usually left implicit. One picks it up "by osmosis."

Comment: @ColeArora: It is easy once you learn a Fitch-style deductive system such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820), where this proof method is simply creating a ∀subcontext ("Given m∈ℤ:") and proving the desired statement ("m is odd ⇒ m^2 is odd.") under that, and then coming back out and using ∀intro to get the desired theorem "∀m∈ℤ ( m is odd ⇒ m^2 is odd ).".

Comment: Also, note that if you want to stay within idiomatic English, you should not use the bare "let" for ∀subcontexts. The one you cited is still alright because of the word "arbitrary", but if you omit that then you would be simply using incorrect English. In contrast, the "let/choose k∈ℤ such that m = 2k+1" is an ∃elim step, for which "let" is correct. See [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18155/1550) for details.

Answer (score 2):

During a proof, there are two things present at any point in time:

- the thing(s) you want to proof right now (which I will call the **goal**(s) )
- and the things you are assuming right now, the things you can use to continue in your proof (referred to as the **context**).

Let's go through the proof you want to do, keeping track of both the context on the left and the goal on the right.
At the start we have
$$
\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c} 
\text{Context} & \text{Goal} \\
\hline 
 & \hspace{1em} \forall m \, (m \text{ is odd } \Rightarrow m^2 \text{ is odd})  \hspace{1em}
\end{array}}
$$
So our goal is something of the form $\forall x \, \varphi(x)$. How do we show this in general?

> We can conclude $\forall x \, \varphi(x)$ from the context $\Gamma$ if we can show $\varphi(y)$ for a variable $y$ which does not appear as a free variable in either the context $\Gamma$ or $\varphi(x)$.

In our case $y$ would actually satisfy this and thus we get a new goal
$$
\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c} 
\text{Context} & \text{Goal} \\
\hline 
 &  \hspace{1em} y \text{ is odd } \Rightarrow y^2 \text{ is odd}  \hspace{1em}
\end{array}}
$$
Why is it fine to simply get rid of the quantification and replace $m$ with $y$? Well, we **did not simply get rid** of the quantification. We had to **make sure that $y$ is not free** in the context and the right side! This condition assures that the context can not have any information about the variable $y$ for us. So we are not assuming anything about $y$, we know nothing about it and thus $y$ can truly be considered to be anything/general. And so if we show the right side for a variable we can consider general, the argument is that we have shown $\forall m [\dots]$.

Now let's continue with the proof. To show the implication you assume whats on the left and try to show whats on the right.
$$
\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c} 
\text{Context} & \text{Goal} \\
\hline 
\hspace{1em}  y \text{ is odd }  \hspace{1em} & 
\hspace{1em}  y^2 \text{ is odd} \hspace{1em}
\end{array}}
$$
In order to continue we need to write out the definition of *odd*
$$
\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c} 
\text{Context} & \text{Goal} \\
\hline 
\hspace{1em} \exists k \, (y = 2k + 1) \hspace{1em} &  
\hspace{1em} \exists k \, (y^2 = 2k + 1)  \hspace{1em}
\end{array}}
$$
Now at this point you can apply existential instantiation on the statement $\exists k \, (y = 2k + 1)$ in your context. What happens here is that you are allowed to replace $\exists k \, (y = 2k + 1)$ by $(y = 2z + 1)$ for any variable $z$ that does not appear free in your context and goal. Similarly to before, this now makes sure that the only thing you know about $z$ is that it satisfies $y = 2z + 1$. So we get
$$
\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c} 
\text{Context} & \text{Goal} \\
\hline 
\hspace{1em}  y = 2z + 1 \hspace{1em} & 
\hspace{1em} \exists k \, (y^2 = 2k + 1) \hspace{1em}
\end{array}}
$$

---

This explanation is basically a verbalization of some of the rules for [natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction), which is a formal way of describing proofs. So if you haven't yet and really want to learn more about proofs in detail, this would be a topic to get into; although it's a deep dive.

Comment: This is well-explained. I ended up putting a pause on Velleman's _How to Prove It_ to go through the more elementary _Introduction to Formal Logic_ (2e) by Peter Smith, which focuses on natural deduction, and it has been helpful in understanding Velleman in particular and informal mathematical proofs in general.

Comment: @ColeArora Ah, I'm a big fan of Smith's books! I don't think I could give you any better recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

$m$ is a variable in that its value is not fixed, but due to the relation between $m$ and $k$ once you fix one of them you determine the value of the other (and $m$ must be odd). You are not proving the statement for particular constants but for arbitrary ones, which is to say, variables.

Answer (score 0):

You say:  "They also can't be free variables, because if they were, then, for example, the sentence being proved true after the introduction of arbitrary integer $m$ -- namely that if $m$ is odd then $m^2$ is odd -- would be a predicate and not even have a truth value."  I would say this a little differently.  A predicate does not have a truth value until values are assigned to the free variables.  But if you assign values to the free variables, then a predicate has a truth value.

Now, let me suggest a slightly different version of Lereau's answer.  I like the idea of distinguishing between context and goal, but I would say that the context consists of two things: a specification of which variables are assumed to have values assigned to them, and a specification of which statements are assumed to be true (these are called "givens" in my book).  With this modified version of Lereau's idea of context, let me go through the proof.  We start with:

- Context:  empty; that is, no variables are assumed to have values and no givens are assumed to be true
- Goal:  $\forall m(m \text{ is odd} \Rightarrow m^2 \text{ is odd})$

When you write "Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ be arbitrary," you change the situation to:

- Context: variables: $m$; givens: none
- Goal:  $m \text{ is odd} \Rightarrow m^2 \text{ is odd}$

So now you are assuming that $m$ stands for something (so the goal, which contains $m$ as a free variable, has a truth value), but you are making no assumption about what $m$ stands for, so it could be anything.  Now you assume $m$ is odd:

- Context: variables: $m$; givens: $m$ is odd
- Goal:  $m^2$ is odd

Writing out the definition of "odd", this means:

- Context: variables: $m$; givens: $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}(m = 2k+1)$
- Goal:  $\exists j \in \mathbb{Z}(m^2 = 2j+1)$

Now since the given is an existential statement, we can introduce the variable $k$  to stand for an integer such that $m = 2k+1$:

- Context:  variables: $m$, $k$; givens:  $m = 2k+1$
- Goal:  $\exists j \in \mathbb{Z}(m^2 = 2j+1)$

Now $m$ and $k$ are both assumed to have values assigned to them, and the statement $m = 2k+1$ is assumed to be true with those values assigned.  Now it is just simple algebra to come up with the value of $j$ that demonstrates that the goal is true.

Comment: I agree with this! Please see my comments on the other post starting from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9833042). In particular note how the Fitch-style subcontexts can precisely capture what you are referring to here. Also note that your mental version requires creating a new subcontext for every ∃elim, instead of how it is done in my linked system. These are two kinds of Fitch-style systems. From my experience, the kind I chose is better (despite the slight increase in complexity) as it is actually usable for actual mathematics way beyond toy logic problems.